# Project Server 2007 install issue - ProjectEventService won't start

Tags: sharepoint, configuration, microsoft-project

Trying to install PS2007 with SP1 on Server 2003.  The install goes fine, but 
when running the SharePoint Configuration Wizard, it fails at stage 6 of 12 
with the error:

> Failed to register SharePoint
>   Services.  An exception of type 
>   System.InvalidOperationException was
>   thrown. Additional exception 
>   information: Cannot start service
>   ProjectEventService on computer '.'.

From the PSCDiagnostics log:

> Exception:
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Cannot start service 
>   ProjectEventService on computer '.'.
>   --->  System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:
>   The service did not respond to the 
>   start or control request in a timely
>   fashion.

The ProjectEventService (Microsoft Office Project Server Event) won't even 
start manually using the Network Service account.  Starting the service with 
a domain account works, but subsequently running the Config Wizard causes the 
service to be removed and re-provisioned to run using the Network Service 
account, which again fails.

Presumably Network Service needs elevated permissions, but even adding it to 
the local Admin group makes no difference.

Anyone come across this sort of issue before?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen when the server is low on resources (slow CPU or not enough RAM - you should have at least 2GB). Also sometimes when there are network issues as I believe this service tries to contact Microsoft for some reason. And also sometimes just because that's what it does...

This should be fixable by increasing the service start time-out. Go to [KB article 824344](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824344) and search for 'time-out'. Make the timeout at least 5 minutes, maybe 10 if you still have problems and it should work correctly!

By the way, trying to change the account the service uses isn't recommended unless you do it through stsadm or SharePoint Central Admin.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue today, the account that is used to start the service needs access to the internet to get the following certificates revocation list:

http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/CodeSignPCA.crl

More infomation can be found at http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.project.server&tid=0ed80ffd-693b-427b-ba57-5ab819554055&p=1